# Verifying every answer before posting?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Is it a etiquette or requirement that every answer needs to be verified before being posted? In one of the questions here : [How can i use Now as a time filter in reports?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11693/how-can-i-use-now-as-a-time-filter-in-reports), I saw that the question got a spontaneous please verify before you post your answer. Even though it was not in any derogatory intention, is this a part of what needs to be done/ good to do !!!!

Comment: If you haven't tried it maybe post it as a comment, and come back and create an answer once you've tried it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd say, unless you know something for sure (i.e. you did it recently and it worked), try it out before posting as an answer. Helps both you and the original poster.

Comment: I tend to only answer if I'm confident that it's correct. Sometimes my syntax may be off (because I write the code in browser) but if if I think that could be the case I call it out in the answer itself.

Comment: @LaceySnr WRT syntax, I always cover myself with "you need something like" at the start or a "caveat emptor - may not compile" at the end.

Answer (score 5):

As I was the one who received that response, I'll say that I did indeed test that formula before posting it. Apparently, I didn't test it in the proper context because the Report Editor did accept it when I edited an existing report!:(

Afterward, I tested it again in a new report in a different context and it wouldn't accept the filter formula. So, my bad in that sense.

All I can say is that we're all human and sometimes we're going to post things in response to a question that either we've misunderstood the context of (easy to do here), misread, or made an error of some kind when posting our response to it. At the same time, that's also one of the many reasons multiple answers can be posted here.